# tweetsharp - app stops being able to tweet after a few hours

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, tweetsharp

I have a asp.net 4.5 webforms site that allows users to link their account to twitter and tweet directly from my site.

My app is registered with twitter and I am able to successfully authorise my app for the user's account and initially can tweet fine, but after a few hours the tweets stop working. I am using tweetsharp to handle the authorisation.

my code is:

```
TwitterClientInfo twitterClientInfo = new TwitterClientInfo();
        twitterClientInfo.ConsumerKey = ConsumerKey;
        twitterClientInfo.ConsumerSecret = ConsumerSecret;
        var requestToken = new OAuthRequestToken { Token = oauthtoken };
        TwitterService twitterService = new TwitterService(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
        OAuthAccessToken accessToken = twitterService.GetAccessToken(requestToken, oauthverifier);
        twitterService.AuthenticateWith(accessToken.Token, accessToken.TokenSecret);
        TwitterUser user = twitterService.VerifyCredentials(new VerifyCredentialsOptions());

        SendTweetOptions options = new SendTweetOptions();
        options.Status = tweetText;
        twitterService.SendTweet(options);
```

what i have noticed is that while the app is successfully tweeting, the accessToken.Token value that is being used to authenticate the user has a proper value (a long string of numbers and upper/lowercase characters) however when it stops tweeting the accessToken.Token value is just a single question mark "?".

Twitter says it doesn't expire tokens so i am at a loss to understand what is happening or how it can be resolved? if i went in to my twitter account and deauthorised my app and went through the authorisation again it would work fine for a few hours, but obviously that's not something i can ask my users to do.

can anyone suggest a resolution to this - either to stop the accessToken value becoming ? or to handle it and get a proper value if it does (without reauthorising the app)

Answer (score 1):

Well, without beginning to understand the actual issue, I managed to fix it

Instead of retrieving the access token every time via:

```
 var requestToken = new OAuthRequestToken { Token = oauthtoken };
 OAuthAccessToken accessToken = twitterService.GetAccessToken(requestToken, oauthverifier);
    twitterService.AuthenticateWith(accessToken.Token, accessToken.TokenSecret);
```

i only do that once and store accessToken.Token and accessToken.TokenSecret in the database and retrieve them when tweeting and supply them

```
twitterService.AuthenticateWith(accessTokenFromDB, accessokenSecretFromDB);
```

I have seen somewhere that Twitter doesn't expire tokens, so this should work. Certainly it's been working for me all weekend whereas the original code would stop working after a few hours.

Thought this might help some others who have the same issue.